# Does it really help in creating index on these properties?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
(p:Product {name:"xxx"})-[r:Has_Attribute]->(a:Attributes{name:"xx", price:"xx", shop:"xxx"})
```

Does it help a lot if I create index on name, price and shop for the Attributes label?

1. If my query starts from the Product node, so probably it doesn't speed up by creating these indexes for Attributes nodes, since given a product, there is a very limited search space for the Attributes nodes.
2. If my query starts from the Attributes, i.e. the Product is unknown, so the index on Attributes will be helpful, since it needs to search for all the attributes nodes.

So it depends on my query. Is my understanding right?

Comment: I think so, but I suggest you to create the indexes in a reduced data set and `PROFILE` both queries to see the indexes usage.

Comment: @BrunoPeres That's right. Another question i want to confirm is that I can't use variable in node label in query like "p:$prod", which $prod is a variable passed in from my method, but property value can be variable, i.e. name:$name. Is that right? It would be great if node label can be variable too in my application.

Comment: it would be great if both property key and node label can be variables.